# Error while making http request from spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am using internal service which uses `org.asynchttpclient` library for HTTP request. From my Spark app when a remote http call is made I am seeing `Http 408`. The request goes through haproxy, and looks like the request fails to complete with following error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.<init>()V from class org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.Channels
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.Channels.initChannelId(Channels.java:67)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyChannelConnector$1.onSuccess(NettyChannelConnector.java:90)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:26)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
```